# Bootstrap 3 carousel with a dynamic source in asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a carousel of bootstrap 3 and I'm confused if I can make the source `<img src=''>` dynamic.

The idea is to have in a modal (PopUp in Devextreme/Devexpress) this carousel and take an Id from a table (dxDataGrid Devextreme).

Right now I have the DataGrid with column that has a button which brings the modal, it execute the carousel with some test data and works fine, but it doesn't bring the data of that Id, I have some code for the modal and controller but I don't know how to get the data from the controller and send the Id to the controller, I'm new in web development.

I'm using bootstrap 3, asp net mvc, c#, Devextreme (the datagrid), JavaScript (for some devextreme component events)

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slider" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">   
     <img class="img-responsive center-block" src='here is a base64'
      </div>
    </div>
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
//HomeController 
public JsonResult getPhoto(string idFlete)
{
  var resultado = HomeModel.retornoFotoServidor;
  string[] strFotosBase = resultado.ToArray();
  return Json(strFotosBase, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

```
//HomeModel
public static List<string> retornoFotoServidor
 {
   get
   {//Here is a code of SQL to bring the Base64 string, add "data:image/jpeg;base64," and return it as list to the controller
}
```

What I expect is to have different images based on the Id of the Datagrid, I don't know how to bring the data from the controller to the src of the carousel, I'm really new on web dev, maybe someone can guide me to the answer or guide me to some info, thanks for the time